# Computing the variance of an estimator

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having some trouble figuring out the proper estimator for the following problem.

Given three random samples $ X_1 $, $ X_2 $ and $ X_3 $ from a normal distribution $ N(\mu, \sigma^2) $, compute the variance of the estimator

$$ T = \frac{X_1+2X_2-X_3}{2} $$

Here's what I tried:

$$ T = \frac{X_1+2X_2-X_3}{2} = \frac{1}{2}X_1 + X_2 - \frac{1}{2}X_3 $$
$$ Var(T) = Var(\frac{1}{2}X_1) + Var(X_2) - Var(\frac{1}{2}X_3) $$

Then, since $ Var(rY) = r^2 Var(Y) $

$$ Var(T) = \frac{1}{4}\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 - \frac{1}{4}\sigma^2 = \sigma^2 $$

However, the correct answer should be $ \frac{3}{2}\sigma^2 $. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: View it as $\tfrac12 X_1+X_2+(-\tfrac12 X_3)$ and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sign mistake.  For any real random variable $X$, it holds that $Var(X) = Var(-X)$. So your calculation should be

$$ Var(T) = Var(\frac{1}{2}X_1) + Var(X_2) + Var(\frac{1}{2}X_3) $$

where we assume that the samples are independent.

Therefore,

$$ Var(T) = \frac{1}{4}\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 + \frac{1}{4}\sigma^2 = 1.5\sigma^2 $$

Comment: Ah there's the error. Thanks!